# Read values from DB and save in a variable

Tags: javascript, react-native

I'm trying to fix this problem but I don't understand how to do.

Basically I have a DB in which there are users's informations. These information could be modify throught a form. When a user want modify the values,  it is done a search in a DB with the user's FiscalCode.
When the user is find, I want to save the old data in a variable, because if I leave a field empty (or I don't change the data) the old data has been deleted. In this way I use the old data.

So the problem is that, If the user has just registered he has no data other than the FirstName, LastName and Email, in this way all the other fields are empty.

*The problem is that when I go to read these data to be saved in the variable if they are empty, I am in error and therefore the change is impossible.* (the error is in **readUtente** function)

I have tried this method adding an "If" but it doesn't work.

```
    componentDidMount(){
    this.readUtente(this.props.cf)
    console.log("this.props.cf: " + this.props.cf)
  }


  //Funzione di prova aggiunta 
  readUtente(cf){
    let params = {};
    params = {
    //  "Person.FiscalCode": this.props.cf
        "Person.FiscalCode": cf
    };
    console.log("1. PARAMS IN MODIFICA PROFILO: " +JSON.stringify(params))
    global.utente.db.localdb().find({
        selector: params
      })
      .then(response => {
      let utente = response.docs[0];
        console.log("2. UTENTE: " + JSON.stringify(utente))
        console.log("3. Utente.Person.FirstName: " + utente.Person.FirstName)
        console.log("4. utente.Person.City: " + utente.Person.City)
        //ho aggiunto if 
       if(utente.Person.FirstName !== undefined) {this.setState({ nome: utente.Person.FirstName })}
       if(utente.Person.LastName !== undefined) {this.setState({ cognome: utente.Person.LastName })}
       if(utente.Person.City !== undefined) {this.setState({ citta: utente.Person.City })} 
       if(utente.Person.Address !== undefined) {this.setState({ indirizzo: utente.Person.Address })}
       if(utente.Person.DateOfBirth !== undefined) {this.setState({ dataNascita: utente.Person.DateOfBirth })}
       if(utente.Person.Country !== undefined) {this.setState({ paese: utente.Person.Country })}
       if(utente.Contacts.Email !== undefined) {this.setState({ email: utente.Contacts.Email })}

      })
      .catch(function(err) {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(err));
      })
  }

  findUtente(cf) {
    console.log("5. Codice fiscale Passato: " + cf)
    let params = {};

    params = {
      "Person.FiscalCode": cf
    };
    console.log("6. PARAMS della findUtente" + JSON.stringify(params))
    global.utente.db
      .localdb()
      .find({
        selector: params
      })
      .then(response => {
        let utente = response.docs[0];
        console.log("7. Utente: " + JSON.stringify(utente))
        console.log("8. this.state.City: " + this.state.citta)
        utente.Person.FirstName = this.state.FirstName == null ? this.state.nome : this.state.FirstName;
        console.log("9. utente.Person.FirstName: " + utente.Person.FirstName)
        utente.Person.LastName = this.state.LastName == null ? this.state.cognome : this.state.LastName;
        console.log("10. utente.Person.LastName: " + utente.Person.LastName)
        utente.Person.City = this.state.City == null ? this.state.citta : this.state.City;
        console.log("11. utente.Person.City: " + utente.Person.City)
        utente.Person.Address = this.state.Address == null ? this.state.indirizzo : this.state.Address;
        utente.Person.DateOfBirth = this.state.DateOfBirth == null ? this.state.dataNascita : this.state.DateOfBirth;
        utente.Person.Country = this.state.Country == null ? this.state.paese : this.state.Country;
        utente.Contacts.Email = this.state.Email == null ? this.state.email : this.state.Email;

        return global.utente.db.localdb().put(utente);
      })
      .catch(function(err) {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(err));
      })
      .finally(function() {
        Actions.homepageutente();
      });
  }
```

CONSOLE:

```
    1. PARAMS IN MODIFICA PROFILO: {"Person.FiscalCode":"ZMBNNZ91P16F364F"}
ModificaProfilo.js:34 this.props.cf: ZMBNNZ91P16F364F
ModificaProfilo.js:51 2. UTENTE: {"DocumentType":"GeneralData","Person":{"FirstName":"Nunzio","LastName":"Zambrotti","FiscalCode":"ZMBNNZ91P16F364F"}
ModificaProfilo.js:52 3. Utente.Person.FirstName: Nunzio
ModificaProfilo.js:53 4. utente.Person.City: undefined
ModificaProfilo.js:67 {}
ModificaProfilo.js:72 5. Codice fiscale Passato: ZMBNNZ91P16F364F
ModificaProfilo.js:78 6. PARAMS della findUtente{"Person.FiscalCode":"ZMBNNZ91P16F364F"}
ModificaProfilo.js:86 7. Utente: {"DocumentType":"GeneralData","Person":{"FirstName":"Nunzio","LastName":"Zambrotti","FiscalCode":"ZMBNNZ91P16F364F"}
ModificaProfilo.js:87 8. this.state.City: undefined
ModificaProfilo.js:89 9. utente.Person.FirstName: Nunzio
ModificaProfilo.js:91 10. utente.Person.LastName: Zambrotti
                      11. utente.Person.City: Rome
```

Comment: Are you sure that the empty data comes as null? Couldn't it be an empty string ' ', or even undefined?

Comment: No I don't know it could be

Comment: Can you paste me an example response you get of utente.Person?

Comment: @Auticcat I edit post

Comment: can you show me the ("UTENTE: " + JSON.stringify(utente)) log?

Comment: Anyone can help?

Comment: So it fails? you go into the catch(err) ?

Comment: Yes I go there!

Comment: Than there's a problem with the call you are making, it fails for a reason, you have to find out why

Comment: I have tried with another user that has all the data and the modify goes right. The problem is if the field is empty

Comment: Could it be that it gives error if the CF is not found?

Comment: No it is printed in the console

Comment: Maybe the server is trying to send City but if not defined faild and sends you back an error?

Comment: Maybe it is the problem.. I Show you the complete console

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196251/discussion-between-jack23-and-auticcat).

Answer (score 0):

The problem could be that the empty data isn't valorised as null but could be an empty string or undefined.

Try changing the if statements in these ways:

```
if(utente.Contacts.Email !== undefined )
```

or

```
if(utente.Contacts.Email !== "" )
```

or

```
if(utente.Contacts.Email)
```

Comment: In the console I have always this ModificaProfilo.js:65 {}

Comment: that is the console.log(JSON.stringify(err))